# Typescript: is it possible to expose global variables using `declare const` without module

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have a globally available variable (without import) `User` to I can later do `User.findById()` in any file.

I have a `User.ts` file with: 

`interface UserInstance{
  ...
}
interface UserClass {
  findById(id:number):UserInstance
  ...
}
declare const User: UserClass`

I was expecting that in another file (let's say `UserService.ts`), I would be able to do `User.findById(1)` (without import), but I get `TS 2304: Cannot find name 'User'`.

My `tsconfig.json` is

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "api/**/*",
    "tests/**/*"
  ]
}`

And `User.ts` is in `api/models` so I assume that the TypeScript compiler would see it when compiling `UserService.ts` that is in `api/services`.

I am new to TypeScript, is it even possible to have global variables not coming from a module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is:

`declare global {
  const User: UserClass;
}`

Also, I initially added it to a `globals.d.ts` in the folder `types`, but according to my `tsconfig.json`, it needed to be in a folder in the `include` list.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `export` them: `export const User: UserClass` and then import where you want to use it of course

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to have `User` available without import.

Comment: You could use a class like this perhaps: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YRvZeq?editors=0011